# printf function pass variable to the javascript

Tags: php, javascript

```
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      function set(n) {

         alert(n);
        document.forms[0].submit();    
      }
    </script>


 $a='A0001';

 printf('<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="set(%g);"/>', $a);
```

Comment: i want to get the $a values...but the values is showed 0 ....Someone can help me to fix the bug ?

Answer (score 2):

`%g` is for numbers, your data contains a number but also has letters in it, so you need a string. Use `%s` instead.

Then the PHP will output:

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="set(A0001);"/>
```

You have no variable called `A0001`, so you are passing `undefined`.

Presumably you want to take the value as a string, so it needs to be quoted. The `json_encode` function will convert a data structure to something suitable for passing to JavaScript. The `htmlspecialchars` function will make a some text suitable for placing in an HTML attribute value.

```
printf('<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="set(%s);"/>', htmlspecialchars(json_encode($a)));
```

Comment: Or, just add quotes inside set() - set("A0001")

Comment: @Ashley — As a manual solution for this specific set of input data, that would work (although it still needs converting to `&quot;` since it is inside an HTML attribute value delimited by `"` characters). I prefer robuster, generic solutions where possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `%s` as your variable contain numeric as well as alphanumeric characters.

Follow this code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  function set(n) {
     alert(n);
    document.forms[0].submit();    
  }
</script>

<?php
$a='A0001';
printf('<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="set(\'%s\');"/>', $a);
?>
```

This is a tested version.